# changing the dimensions of images to half in PIL

Tags: python, image-processing

There is a image which has the dimensions of 1920 x 1080 i want to reduce it to half

my code :-

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('MysticHorizon.jpg')
# new_image = image.resize((960, 540)) I dont want to do it like this
# new_image.save('imageresized.jpg')
i = (image.size)
for a in i:
    a = int(a/2)
    print(a)
    
for j in a:
    print(j, end= ",")
newimage = image.resize((a))
newimage.save('halfresized.jpg')
```

I am getting an error

"    for j in a:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size method returns a tuple. The first loop splits the tuple and the second loop tries to iterate the last element of the tuple which is an integer, hence the error.

To reduce the image size, try this code:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('MysticHorizon.jpg')
i = image.size   # current size (height,width)
i = i[0]//2, i[1]//2  # new size
newimage = image.resize(i)
newimage.save('halfresized.jpg')
```

Comment: "i[0]//2" why there is a two forward slash? why not only one? and what does the two forward slashes do?

Comment: The double slash returns an integer. A single slash always returns a float. The `resize` method requires integers.